Justifying uneven group sizes in an incomplete counterbalanced measures design using a balanced Latin square
I'm working on the statistical analysis of an experiment where we showed 6 videos to a group of people and asked them to rate their effectiveness. In order to handle bias due to the order, we divided the participants into 6 groups and then chose the order for the videos according to a balanced Latin square. The problem is that not everyone completed the survey, and the group sizes ended up being uneven. It's now not possible to run any more trials.
We have no choice but to use the data as is. What I am wondering is whether anyone here can give some advice on how to phrase things in the paper. In other words, how do I say "it didn't go quite according to plan but the order in which they watched the videos is still mixed enough that the results are solid" in a way that's appropriate for a research article.
Four of the groups ended with about 40 participants, one had 20, and the last had 10.
Thanks,
Greg

do the participants rate effectiveness of each video independently (i.e. on a scale of 1-10) or do they rank their effectiveness (i.e. each video gets a scores of 1-6 but two videos can't have the same score)?

Hi Spätzle, thanks for your response. The answer to your question is, basically, some of each. They were asked a number of questions, basically on a scale 1-10 (more like 1-4 usually), and then at the end were asked to rank the videos.
